# what is the meaning of NOP in the schematic diagram?

Tags: capacitor, resistors

what is the meaning of NOP in the schematic diag[image: r]am?

Answer (score 7):

It is likely short for "no place" or "no populate", indicating that no component is to be placed in that location during assembly. Another common abbreviation for this is DNP, short for "do not place".

Answer (score 2):

As Alex said, it is a part property in Sch. Usually, all SCH Tools has a property for each  part called "Loading" property. Loading property can be set based on if the part will be loaded or not in the circuit. Their can be multiple reasons to do that. Some are :-

1. Uncertain about the part in circuit.
2. To give multiple configurable options.
3. To be used in diff way in Diff scenarios.
4. Multiple Variants of Sch.

Usually it is good to assign a color to this property to highlight such NOP(No Populate), or DNP (Do Not Place) or NM(NoMount) parts.

Answer (score 0):

Question as been answered, but it also looks like the resisters are really jumpers. Based on the 0 ohm value. If so, looks dangerous, could easily short vcc and gnd